Playing the trumpet with a mute as a default
I want to learn playing the trumpet.
Purely as a hobby, by myself, in a small apartment with neighbors. Which means that playing the trumpet, as is, is not an option, for it is way too loud.
The only solution I see is to use a mute, specifically the "Yamaha Silent Brass SB-7X" (because it is the only mute available in my area).
I know that a mute might affect the sound and the way of playing, which might not be a big deal if one has to use it "once in a while", but how about having it as a permanent set-up?
Will it cause me to develop a completely wrong habits and techniques? Make me never know how the trumpet should really sound? Any other potential downsides I am not even considering (taking into account I never played a trumpet before)?

This question is similar to: What is the quietest way to practice trumpet that is still doable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Situations and opinions and experiences vary a lot, from "it's OK and fine" to "it totally messed up my playing", so there can be no objective correct answer, unless all aspects are covered. Here's a great thread, including the aspect of playing exclusively with mutes, with many opinions and insights https://www.trumpetherald.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=158028    Pragmatically speaking, if your options are (A) to play a muted trumpet, or (B) not to play any kind of trumpet at all, then if you want to play at least some kind of trumpet, I guess you can figure out which of those options has that.

See also https://music.stackexchange.com/q/120479/78419, https://music.stackexchange.com/q/24855/78419, https://music.stackexchange.com/q/32025/78419

It's not ideal. You'll be learning to play an instrument that responds somewhat differently to a 'real' trumpet.   And don't kid yourself about HOW quiet it makes you.  Volume is reduced, perhaps from 90dB to 70dB.  But that's still far from silent, and a neighbour inclined to complain will still do so.

Why isn't it ideal? That's the core of what OP is asking.

@Aaron - ideal relates to a perfect solution. A mute which quietens, but not silences the trumpet will not produce a perfect solution to the neighbour problem.

And it also relates to practicing on something that doesn't respond like a real trumpet.

@Tim I know perfectly well why it's not ideal. I'm saying this post needs to lay it out in more detail to be a useful answer.
